# Not able to view ArcGIS non shared Scene Layer with BuildingSceneLayer even though I have signed in and the file is from my Portal

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am viewing BuildingSceneLayer using ArcGIS Javascript API.

I want to display a SceneLayer which is not shared as public in the ArcGIS portal.

When I try viewing it I get

[Sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb09U.png)

When I view in Codepen

https://codepen.io/arnofiva/pen/c410babb5384945a12b1d8206ebe27ce?editors=1010

```
require([
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/SceneView",
    "esri/layers/BuildingSceneLayer"
], function(Map, SceneView, BuildingSceneLayer) {
    // Create Map
    var map = new Map({
        basemap: "terrain",
        ground: "world-elevation"
    });

    // Create the SceneView
    var view = new SceneView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        camera: {
            position: [-74.0338, 40.6913, 707],
            tilt: 81,
            heading: 50
        }
    });

    // Create SceneLayer and add to the map
    var sceneLayer = new BuildingSceneLayer({
        portalItem: {
            id: "e7bf9f676ed64937bff9f44c84fdae2b"
        },
        popupEnabled: false
    });
    map.add(sceneLayer);

    sceneLayer.when().then(function() {
        view.goTo(sceneLayer.fullExtent);
    });
});
```

I get a popup for logging in. How do I enable that in my code?

Comment: As I understand, it's working in the Codepen you provided. Can you share the code where it's not working?

Comment: I copied the same code to my application and it is not working. The error shown in the screenshot is coming.